# Can't download file from pdf.js viewer

Tags: pdf, download, javascript, file-download

I want to download file
But I am not able to download  file.

Can anyone please help me to download  file

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The site disables the download button in `pdf.js`. But this is a very
lame protection, since `pdf.js` works on the client side and requires
downloading the document into the client's browser in order to display it.

Use this method:

- Display the pdf
- Turn on the browser's developer tools
- Refresh the page
- Look at the HTML requests that are issued to find the URL of the file
- Copy this reference and paste it into the browser's address bar to download
- Rename the downloaded file to `.pdf`
- Done.

Comment: Thanks! More specific instructions to help:
Google chrome browser. Open developer tools. Go to NETWORK tab. Refresh the page. Look for an item in the list of type "XHR" or look by file size. Usually a PDF will be at least 10+kb but could be quite big. Right click on the file name & click open in new tab until you find the pdf.